# Create a datetime using strings in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

What I would like to do is to go from **"2013", "December", "20"** and to create **2013-12-20**.

Does someone have an idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provide nice converters in part of it's framework

```
2.1.2 :001 > "20 december 2013".to_date
 => Fri, 20 Dec 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

For your required format you can use this bit for formatting:

```
strftime("The date is %y-%m-%d")
```

This can be called on any time object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Date.new(2013, 12, 20)
```

You can read more about Date [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to  @Marc-Alexandre Bérubé 's  answer to get your desired format:

```
"20 december 2013".to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# => "2013-12-20"
```